# Conditionally disable cells in Google Sheets if there is not a certain text in a previous cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a sheet that has the following columns:

- A. timestamp
- B. name
- C. email which can contain an actual email or "Needs to be created"
  text
- D. tickboxes

I want do disable cells and put FALSE in column D if there is no "Needs to be created" text in column C.

Here is my code but it does not work. Please helm me fixing it

```
function disableCellsInColumnD() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Experiment");
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("C2:C"); // Assumes data starts from row 2 in column C
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  var checkboxRange = sheet.getRange("D2:D"); // Assumes checkboxes start from row 2 in column D
  var checkboxValues = checkboxRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    var email = dataValues[i][0];
    var checkboxValue = checkboxValues[i][0];

    if (email !== "Needs to be created") {
      checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setValue(false); // i + 2 to account for header row
      checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setBackground("lightgray");
      checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setFontColor("gray");
      checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setDataValidation(null);
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 4).setHorizontalAlignment("center"); // Optional: Center-align cell in column D
    } else {
      if (!checkboxValue) {
        checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setBackground(null);
        checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setFontColor(null);
        checkboxRange.getCell(i + 2, 1).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I  would just do it row by row with onEdit

Comment: How do you disable cells? Your code does not include any [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) Google Apps Script functions or something similar to it. Please provide more details about it.

Comment: Is this something you need to regularly or as a one-off?